# BitMap field in Lucene

Tags: lucene

Is there any way to store a bitmap field in lucene and search using bit mask operations?

I have a lot of boolean attributes for an object and instead of having a separate field for each one I'm considering if there's a way to store every attribute as a bit in a bitmap and search using a bitmask.

The field value coud be something like:

```
Attr 1 | Attr 2 | Attr 3 | Attr 4
  0        1        0        1
```

And if I search for documents with Attr 1 & Attr 3, I'd mask with:

```
Attr 1 | Attr 2 | Attr 3 | Attr 4
  1        0        1        0
```

in a logical AND operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kludge is to convert the bit field to a number, then search on numeric values. For example, if you have "0 1 0 1" convert it to "5" then search on "5". But, this does not work directly for "find all documents with Attr 4" if the documents can have other attributes -- you need to search on (in query parser syntax):

```
+(1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15)
```

(this assumes that "Attr 4" becomes the least-significant bit in the resulting numeric value (and that the default operator is OR)).